# What is homomorphism exactly?

Tags: haskell, math

Homo means equal and homomorphism in Haskell is about preserving the structure.

For instance, the `fmap` function from category *functor*, preserves the structure.

But what does **homomorphism** exactly mean?

Comment: Are we talking about mathematics here, or Haskell? tbh I've not come across the term in Haskell, even though it's ubiquitous in mathematics (at least in abstract algebra).

Comment: if `f (x & y) === f x # f y`, `f` is a homomorphism. I think. [Google says](https://www.google.com/search?q=homomorphism): Wikipedia says: "In algebra, a homomorphism is a structure-preserving map between two algebraic structures of the *same* type (such as two groups, two rings, or two vector spaces). The word homomorphism comes from the ancient Greek language: ὁμός (homos) meaning "same" and μορφή (morphe) meaning "form" or "shape"."

Comment: that's indeed pretty much the definition in mathematics, yes :) I'm tempted to flag this as off-topic unless the OP (or someone else) can demonstrate some Haskell-specific use of the term that they would like explaining.

Comment: Have you tried to google the term?

Comment: @RobinZigmond See [PRG56.pdf](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3378/PRG56.pdf), 1986 "An Introduction to the Theory of Lists" by Richard Bird, for Haskell (well, FP)-related uses of "homomorphism".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to nLab,  [a homomorphism is a function between (the underlying sets) of two algebras that preserves the algebraic structure.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homomorphism)

What is "algebraic structure?"

Abstract algebra studies *algebras* defined by laws. For example, monoids embody the ideas of associativity and identity, and groups add the idea of invertibility. [The set of axioms and laws of the algebra is also called its "algebraic structure." Confusingly, an algebra itself is also called an "algebraic structure"](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+structure)

An example of a group is the set of integers under addition with the identity being 0 and the inverse being -x. Another example of a group is the set of nonzero rational numbers under multiplication with the identity being 1 and the inverse being 1/x.

Now, let's look at group homomorphisms.

Let (G, *, e) denote a group where G is the carrier set, * is the operation, and e is the identity element. Let F be a group homomorphism from group (G, *, e) to group (G', *', e'), and let f be the underlying function from G to G'.

- f (a * b) = f a *' f b
- f e = e'

(Note that [the preservation of inverse follows from the above laws](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupHomomorphism.html).)

This is the meaning of "preserve the structure" for groups.

For rings, the ring structure must be preserved, and so on for other algebraic structures.

See [this Math Stack Exchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1350798).

Now, what about Haskell?

First, a category consists of *objects* and *morphisms* between these objects. These morphisms can be composed associatively, and each object has an *identity morphism*, the identity element under composition.

A functor is a morphism between categories. In the context of Haskell, a functor is an endofunctor (an endomorphism maps something to itself) from Hask to Hask*. The type constructor maps the objects of Hask (the Haskell types) and `fmap` maps the morphisms (the Haskell functions). Functors must preserve the *category structure* of identity and composition, hence the functor laws:

- `fmap (g . f) = (fmap g) . (fmap f)`
- `fmap id = id`

*Note that [Hask fails the laws in the presence of `seq`, so it isn't actually a category](http://math.andrej.com/2016/08/06/hask-is-not-a-category/).

Answer (score 6):

Haskell types are not merely collections of isolated values; they can have operations that combine two elements of the same type and return yet another element of the type. For example `String` with [`++`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-), [`Natural`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Numeric-Natural.html) with `+` and `*`, `Bool` with `&&` and `||`.

These operations might or might not satisfy some properties. For example, the associative property (satisfied by all the operations mentioned earlier) or the commutative property (that list append `++` doesn't satisfy). Sometimes a property relates two different operations, like the distributive law relating `+` and `*`.

Suppose we have two different types, and also two different operations, one for each type. For example `String` and `++` on one side, and `Natural` and `+` on the other. The operations are different, but if we squint a little, we see that they both satisfy the associative property.

Now, what if we could find a function that converted `String` values into `Natural` values, in such a way that `+`ing the results of converting two `String`s was always equal to the result of converting the `++`ing of the original `String`s? This is more difficult than simply finding any function whatsoever of type `String -> Natural`. It must be a function that preserves the results of the operations when moving to the other side. This function between the two types is called an *homomorphism*.

For example, the function `length :: String -> Natural` is an homomorphism. The length of the concatenation of two strings is equal to the sum of the original lengths. A function like `length` but which assigned a non-zero value to the empty list would not be a valid homomorphism.

Notice that the homomorphism can "erase" distinctions present in the source type. For example `length` assigns the same number to `"foo"` and `"bar"`.

Another example: consider the type `FilePath` and the operation [`</>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.4.2.1/docs/System-FilePath-Posix.html#v:-60--47--62-) on one side (let's only take relative folder paths into account) and the type `IO ()` and the operation [`>>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--62-) on the other. Then the function [`setCurrentDirectory :: FilePath -> IO ()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.3.2/docs/System-Directory.html#v:setCurrentDirectory) is an homomorphism. Notice that there are values of `IO ()`, for example `putStrLn "foo"`, that do not represent a "change folder" effect and are never "targeted" by `setCurrentDirectory`. This didn't happen with `lenght`, where every `Natural` was the `lenght` of some `String` or another.